# Positive proportion sets of numbers not divisible by twin primes.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, twin-primes

Is it possible to *explicitly* construct a set of integers $S$ which contains a positive proportion of the positive integers and every integer in $S$  is not divisible by any prime $p$ in the set of twin primes $\{3,5,7,11,13,17,19,29,31,\ldots\}$.

**Clarification**

Firstly, by twin prime I mean any prime $p$ where either $p+2$ or $p-2$ is prime.

It is known that approximately $83.83\%$ of all positive integers are divisible by a twin prime (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228349/what-percentage-of-numbers-is-divisible-by-the-set-of-twin-primes)). Therefore, approximately $16.17\%$ of all positive integers avoid being divisible by a twin prime.

I would like to see the *explicit* construction of a set $S$ whose elements avoid divisibility by twin primes. Moreover, I would like this set to contain a positive proportion of all positive integers, that is:

$$\sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ n \in S}} 1 > c x$$

for some $c>0$.

Clearly, one could let $S$ equal the set of numbers not divisible by twin primes, but it would be interesting to see something more explicit such as an arithmetic progression (though I believe this to be impossible).